# How to best combine assets using Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel

I have a question regarding this scenario which is best explained with this code:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/frontend.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/frontend.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap'
    ])
    .scripts([
        'resources/assets/vendor/constellation.min.js'
    ], 'public/js/all.js')
     .styles([
         'resources/assets/vendor/swiper/css/swiper.min.css',
         'resources/assets/css/styles.css'
     ], 'public/css/all.css');
```

As you can see I create a `frontend.js`, `vendor.js`, `frontend.css`, `all.js`, and `all.css`. Now, my question is:

How can I combine all.js/all.css to frontend.js/frontend.css?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use import/require on your JS files for the vendor JS assets and import for the css files? Laravel mix supports this :)

Comment: Thanks @manniL ! That helped a lot and in fact it worked perfectly. Thanks a ton! Feel free to make an answer if you want and I will accept it! :-)

Comment: You are welcome @Chris ! I added the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking on how to combine those assets through Laravel mix, you can simply import/require them through their own logics.

For the Javascript, your can use *import* (ES6) or *require* to include the other JS assets.

The same works with SASS/SCSS, which can *import* CSS through the equally named command.